# How do you run cables into a server cabinet (not rack)?

Tags: rack-layout

First, I am not a network engineer and have no experience in server rack/cabinet set up. I am trying to set up a server cabinet for an observatory. When the observatory is being used, the roof is open, so the room the cabinet is in will be exposed to the elements. This is why I am opting for a cabinet rather than a rack.

My question;

How does one run cables into a server cabinet? Are there any cabinet solutions that allow cables to run into the cabinet?

Thanks for reading.

Simon

Comment: Consult the documentation for your enclosure. There will be ways to get cables (power, data, etc.) into the unit while maintaining the environmental integrity. (outdoor enclosures are usually NEMA rated. those intended for interior use will usually not need that level of isolation.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually from the underground, or maybe from the rear whether the cabinet is attached to the wall. Otherwise, you could find a cabinet with insulated cables shields, that allow you to put more cables inside the same shield. So you will multiple cables inside the shield that will run into your cabinet and will maintain the IP(International Protection) level wanted